# Transferring file from Google to Parse.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, parse-platform, google-drive

I have created a system where user selects files from their Google Drive to be uploaded into Parse.

I have done so separately though, where I have one code that allows user to select an item from Google Drive, and one that allows user to upload a file from their computer into parse.

**Google Drive (Using Google drive picker):**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>eSnail Scan Upload Part 2</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      // The Browser API key obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var developerKey = 'KEY';

      // The Client ID obtained from the Google Developers Console.
      var clientId = 'ID';

      // Scope to use to access user's photos.
      var scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/photos'];

      var pickerApiLoaded = false;
      var oauthToken;

      // Use the API Loader script to load google.picker and gapi.auth.
      function onApiLoad() {
        gapi.load('auth', {'callback': onAuthApiLoad});
        gapi.load('picker', {'callback': onPickerApiLoad});
      }

      function onAuthApiLoad() {
        window.gapi.auth.authorize(
            {
              'client_id': clientId,
              'scope': scope,
              'immediate': false
            },
            handleAuthResult);
      }

      function onPickerApiLoad() {
        pickerApiLoaded = true;
        createPicker();
      }

      function handleAuthResult(authResult) {
        if (authResult && !authResult.error) {
          oauthToken = authResult.access_token;
          createPicker();
        }
      }

      // Create and render a Picker object for picking user Photos.
      function createPicker() {
        if (pickerApiLoaded && oauthToken) {
          var picker = new google.picker.PickerBuilder().
              enableFeature(google.picker.Feature.MULTISELECT_ENABLED).
              addView(google.picker.ViewId.PDFS).
              setOAuthToken(oauthToken).
              setDeveloperKey(developerKey).
              setCallback(pickerCallback).
              build();
          picker.setVisible(true);
        }
      }

      // A simple callback implementation.
      function pickerCallback(data) {
        var url = 'nothing';
        if (data[google.picker.Response.ACTION] == google.picker.Action.PICKED) {
          var doc = data[google.picker.Response.DOCUMENTS][0];
          url = doc[google.picker.Document.URL];

        }
        var message = 'The following(s) were stored in Parse: ' + url;
        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = message;




      }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <div id="demo">

    <!-- The Google API Loader script. -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js?onload=onApiLoad"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**That allows a user to upload a file into Parse (PDF):**

```html
<HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.15.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

  // ***************************************************
  // NOTE: Replace the following your own keys
  // ***************************************************

    Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");

  function saveJobApp(objParseFile)
  {
     var jobApplication = new Parse.Object("Scan");
     jobApplication.set("Name", "");
     jobApplication.set("DocumentName", objParseFile);
     jobApplication.save(null, 
     {
        success: function(gameScore) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place after the object is saved.
          var photo = gameScore.get("profileImg");
          $("#profileImg")[0].src = photo.url();
        },
        error: function(gameScore, error) {
          // Execute any logic that should take place if the save fails.
          // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and description.
          alert('Failed to create new object, with error code: ' + error.description);
        }
     });
  }

  $('#profilePhotoFileUpload').bind("change", function(e) {
         var fileUploadControl = $("#profilePhotoFileUpload")[0];
         var file = fileUploadControl.files[0];
         var name = file.name; //This does *NOT* need to be a unique name
         var parseFile = new Parse.File(name, file);

         parseFile.save().then
         (
           function() 
           {
               saveJobApp(parseFile);
           }, 
           function(error) 
           {
             alert("error");
           }
         );
  }); 

});
</script>

<body>
    <input type="file" id="profilePhotoFileUpload">
    <img id="profileImg"/>
</body>
</HTML>
```

Answer (score 4):

You seem to separately download your file from Google, and then upload to Parse. So the "transfering" in the title is misleading.

Having said that, the code is well-structured but the naming is bad.

---

I find it semantically confusing to call your functions like `onAuthApiLoad`. This tells me nothing about what the function does. 
Now, when I'm reading the line calling this functions, I have no clue what it does. On the other hand, I already see where it is called, so this name is more redundant than helpful:

```
onload=onApiLoad
```

is what I am talking about. The same for:

```
setCallback(pickerCallback)
```

If instead function's name tell me what it does, I can understand the line without even checking the function's definition!

---

I suspect `saveJobApp` is not specific to Job Applications, so a more generic name could be more helpful.

Why `gameScore`???

`fileUploadControl` is prob better to name `fileUploadElement`

---

```
Parse.initialize("ID", "ID");
```

will look better as

```
Parse.initialize("ParseID", "ParseJsKey");
```